# Newtonsoft JSON.NET library unescaping strings incorrectly for my requirements

Tags: json, utf-8, character-encoding, json.net

I have, for example, this turkish character in my Flex (as in "Adobe Flash") app: **ğ**

When the app saves its state to the database it uses JSON representation, and this character becomes escaped to: **\u00c4\u009f**

This is causing me some nuisance, because when unescaping using the JSON.NET method *JsonConvert.DeserializeObject* the **\u00c4\u009f** becomes **Ä** (an umlauted A followed by an invisible character

I think I'm thus faced with the situation where the string was UTF8 on the way in (pre-escaping) but whatever thing inside the Flex app encoded it to JSON might not have realised this, and thus escaped it to the two literal bytes it saw..
Or the encoded format is correct, that really is how a UTF8 string with the Turkish ğ would be after esacping and it's the Newtonsoft lib that is not converting it back using a UTF8 encoding when pulling it out

Whichever tool is getting it wrong, I'm kinda stuck with the data as it is currently presented - that's how it is in the database

What can I do with it to make Newtonsoft JSON.NET give me back a ğ, rather than an Ä[] ?

Comment: It looks like Flex is doing it wrong. First of all, it's saving one character as two. And none of these is a ğ. Perhaps it's not using Unicode but some other encoding. Turkish ğ is 0x11f. Ä is indeed 0xC4, and 9F is indeed invisible.

Answer (score 1):

I believe yu_sha's comment was correct; the data was stored incorrectly. I don't think there's anything that can be done to get JSON.NET to give back the correct data (it's not doing anything wrong, and it's not designed/shouldn't be responsible for fixing mistakes made elsewhere)

I was, however, able to salvage the text I wanted with the following line of C# after JSON.NET had deserialized it:

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetBytes(THE_TEXT));
```

Reason being Flex seems to be storing it as escaped Latin-1. Pulling the raw bytes out using iso-8859-1 encoding and then re-interpreting them as UTF8 patched them up, though I don't doubt that there may be some situations where this hack doesn't work out..